# Stretch stackpanel

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to create a list of songs using a listbox, but I got an issue with the layout.

Currently I use the following xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstHistory" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,284,0,90" Width="460">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="top" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Margin="8"
                                  TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="8"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Text="{Binding Artist}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="8,0,8,8"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Time}" Opacity="0.25" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I would like to have the time on the far right bottom corner of the list item, but every time it ends up in the middle of the screen.

This is an example of what I get:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get the time there?

Comment: You want it to appear at the bottom corner of the screen, but this is an element in a listbox.  You're going to have a `Time` display for every element in the list. Do you want this at the bottom right of the list item?  Upload a screenshot.

Comment: set the HorizontalContentAlignment to "Stretch" on your ListBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` won't work on a StackPanel. You should set an explicit Width (probably 432) instead.

Also, the Image doesn't need to be in a StackPanel all by itself.

Comment: It will work for a StackPanel provided the StackPanel has room to stretch.

Answer (score 5):

By default the ListBoxItem takes up as little space as possible. This is also true for a StackPanel. In order to have it span you must set the HorizontalContentAlignment of the ListBox to Stretch, and set the HorizontalAlignment of the StackPanel to Stretch (which you are already doing). You'll also need to set the ItemContainerStyle for the ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstHistory" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,284,0,90">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="top" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Margin="8"
                              TextWrapping="Wrap"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="8"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Text="{Binding Artist}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="8,0,8,8"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Time}" Opacity="0.25" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```