# How to virtualize data in simple stackpanel in Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, virtualization

I have created a list with ScrollViewer and stackpanel. I am adding user control to this stackpanel from codebehind.
I want to virtualize data that I can improve the performance of my application.
How can i achieve this?

I cann't use Listbox because I am adding user control as DataItems and each user control have a different width and height.. Please suggest how to implement that
**Code:**

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stckPnlComponentsLst" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityInvertedConverter}}" Orientation="Vertical">
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

C#

```
for (int count = 0; count < countItems; count++)
{
    stckPnlComponentsLst.Children.Add(new ChannelNewsLstControl(ViewModel.ComponentData[count], false, false));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ListBox instead. Check the [sample here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/working-with-listbox-in-windows-phone-7/). For example, define ListBox in a xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList">
```

and then in codebehind

```
var MyListData = new List<ChannelNewsLstControl>();
MyListData.Add(new ChannelNewsLstControl {name = "MyFirstChannelName});
MyList.ItemsSource=MyListData;
```

If you have really lots of items, i'd recommend to use [Telerik's DataBoundListBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/raddataboundlistbox-features-asynchronous-balance.html) as it is much faster than a normal ListBox (at least, for wp7) and supports virtualization and async loading. Sample would be pretty the same, as component is inherited ListBox and adding own features mentioned before.

EDIT: final answer:

`Try to put a grid inside of your ItemTemplate and set its RowDefinition.Height = "Auto".` [See some details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604627/windows-phone-listbox-item-height)

Comment: If I use a listbox all the DataItems needs to be of specific size my limitation is that each item will have there own height different. How can I achieve this in Listbox or improve scrollviewer and stackpanel??

Comment: I think, this one is quite close to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640104/stretch-stackpanel. What you need to do is to play with VerticalContentAlignment (if we are talking about height) and with ItemContainerStyle (though, in my similar case it was not necessary).

Comment: Did some investigations today. Just use a StackPanel inside of your DataTemplate if you want your item to take as small space as possible.

Comment: Yes I tried but how can change height and width of my ItemTemplate as per requirement... I can use Variablesizewrapgrid if the items have height and width in multiple but even that is not the case... It varies depending on the text content present in it...

Comment: Ah, i got your point. Try to put a grid inside of your ItemTemplate and set its RowDefinition.Height = "Auto". Some details here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604627/windows-phone-listbox-item-height )

Comment: @BalrajSingh, did setting RowDefinition.Height = "Auto" works for you? I'll edit the answer post in case it works, so others would be able to find answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any case in which using a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer is a good idea.
You should not do that.

There are 2 controls to do what you want, ListBox and ListView.

If you really want to stick with a stackpanel inside a ScrollViewer, just replace your StackPanel, by a VirtualizingStackPanel. But again, you should NOT be doing that.

Comment: I believe that ListView does not exist in Silverlight

Comment: I cann't use Listview or listbox because my list of control that have different sizes.. Items are not consistent with there height and width.

Comment: I am trying to create a list of data with binds user control since each items is a different usercontrol I cann't use Listbox or listview as each dataItem is of different sizes. I used scrollviwer and stackpanel and add these user control from code bind but I am not able to implement visualization. How can I implement visualization?